# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Product"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Bom, estou seguindo um tutorial sobre Node.js e MongoDB e estou tentando criar um produto, portanto crio uma lista de atributos que os objetos terão, até tudo ok. Seguindo o [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiGrfBbvneM&index=16&list=PLHlHvK2lnJndvvycjBqQAbgEDqXxKLoqn) em questão, acontece comigo o mesmo erro ocorrido em 5:39, no entanto a pessoa do video arrumou adicionando a seguinte linha no código dele: `"const Product = require('./models/product');"` 
Porém, quando faço o mesmo, continuo tendo o mesmo erro em questão, onde não consigo identificar o que se encontra de errado, mesmo após tentar re-escrever este pedaço de código. Para maior esclarecimento eis aqui meu código

app.js

```
 const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();

const indexRoute = require('./routes/index-route');
const productsRoute = require('./routes/products-route');


mongoose.connect('mongodb://login:senha@ds058548.mlab.com:58548/ndstr');


const Product = require('./models/product');
```

meu product.js

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = moongose.Schema;

const schema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    slug:{
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
    tags: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', schema);
```

product-controller.js

```
'use strict';

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Product = mongoose.model('Product');

exports.post = (req, res, next) => {
    var product = new Product(req.body);
    product.save().then(x => {
        res.status(201).send({ mesage: "Produto cadastrado com sucesso!'" });
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: '[ERRO] Falha durante cadastro!',
            data: e
        });
    });
    res.status(201).send(req.body);
};
exports.put = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    res.status(200).send({
        id: id,
        item: req.body
    });
};
exports.delete = (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(201).send(req.body);
};
```

Comment: Da uma olhada nesses tutoriais de node da [Rocketseat](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BN_8bCfVp88&list=PL85ITvJ7FLoiXVwHXeOsOuVppGbBzo2dp) são muitos bons além de dar dicas de boas praticas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **app.js**

*Não a necessidade de instânciar o produto no app sendo que já foi feito no controller, no app fica só abertura da conexão.*

Necessário se versão do mongoose for maior que 5.3.10
 `useNewUrlParser: true  useCreateIndex: true`

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false}));

const indexRoute = require('./routes/index-route');
const productsRoute = require('./routes/products-route');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://login:senha@ds058548.mlab.com:58548/ndstr',
    { 
        useNewUrlParser: true , 
        useCreateIndex: true
    });

//const Product = require('./models/product');

app.use('/produtos', productsRoute);
```

> **product.js**

*Alterei a forma como instancia o schema.*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const Schema = moongose.Schema;
//const schema = new mongoose.Schema({
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    slug:{
        type: String, 
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        index: true,
        unique: true
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    active: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true,
        default: true
    },
    tags: [{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema );
```

> **controller.js**

*Alterei a forma como instância o model.*

```
//const mongoose = require('mongoose');
//const Product = mongoose.model('Product');
const Product = require('../models/Product')

exports.post = (req, res, next) => {
    var product = new Product(req.body);
    product.save().then(x => {
        res.status(201).send({ mesage: "Produto cadastrado com sucesso!'" });
    }).catch(e => {
        res.status(400).send({
            message: '[ERRO] Falha durante cadastro!',
            data: e
        });
    });
    res.status(201).send(req.body);
};
exports.put = (req, res, next) => {
    const id = req.params.id;
    res.status(200).send({
        id: id,
        item: req.body
    });
};
exports.delete = (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(201).send(req.body);
};
```

Comment: Perfeito mano! obrigado!